# how to pinch zoom image in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

i have tableview -> custom cell -> uiscrollview -> uiimageview

how to pinch and zoom uiscrollview..

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   methods are not working for me.
```

My code is :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        objCellfullscreen.scroll.maximumZoomScale = 6.0f;
        objCellfullscreen.scroll.minimumZoomScale= 0.5f;
        objCellfullscreen.scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
        objCellfullscreen.scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 460);
        objCellfullscreen.scroll.delegate =self;

    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";



        objCellfullscreen =(cellFullScreen *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (objCellfullscreen==nil) {
              .......
              ...........
              .........
      }
      return  objCellfullscreen;
    }
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{

    CGFloat offsetX = (objCellfullscreen.scroll.bounds.size.width > objCellfullscreen.scroll.contentSize.width)?(objCellfullscreen.scroll.bounds.size.width - objCellfullscreen.scroll.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    CGFloat offsetY = (objCellfullscreen.scroll.bounds.size.height > objCellfullscreen.scroll.contentSize.height)?(objCellfullscreen.scroll.bounds.size.height - objCellfullscreen.scroll.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    objCellfullscreen.img.center = CGPointMake(objCellfullscreen.scroll.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,objCellfullscreen.scroll.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);

}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return objCellfullscreen.img;
}
```

Thanks.. and please help.

Comment: Hope you set up UIScrollView delegate in .h file also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have a scroll view inside a tableview as `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, this is probably why some delegate methods of the scroll view aren't called/ called sporadically.